# SQL transform id and add where statement before join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am pretty new to SQL. Here is an operation I am sure is simple for a lot of you. I am trying to join two tables across databases on the same server – dbB and dbA, and `TableA` (with IdA) and `TableB` (with IdB) respectively. But before doing that I want to transform column `IdA` into a number, where I would like to remove the “:XYZ” character from its values and add a where statement for another column in dbA too. Below I show my code for the join but I am not sure how to convert the values of the column. This allows me to match `idA`with `idB` in the join. Thanks a ton in advance.

```
Select replace(idA, “:XYZ”, "")
from dbA.TableA guid
where event like “%2015”
left join dbB.TableB own
on guid.idA = own.idB
```

Comment: You'd replace on the join or have to use a subquery so the replaced values exist prior to the join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things

1. FROM, Joins, WHERE (unless you use subqueries) syntax order it's also the order of execution (notice select isn't listed as its near the end in order of operation but first syntactically!)
2. alias/fully qualify columns when multiple tables are involved so we know what field comes from what table.
3. order of operations has the SQL doing the from and JOINS 1st thus what you do in the select isn't available (not in scope yet) for the compiler, this is why you can't use select column aliases in the from, where or even group by as well.
4. I don't like Select * usually but as I don't know what columns you really need... I used it here.
5. As far as where before the join.  most SQL compilers anymore use cost based optimization and figure out the best execution plan given your data tables and what not involved.  So just put the limiting criteria in the where in this case since it's limiting the left table of the left join.  If you needed to limit data on the right table of a left join, you'd put the limit on the join criteria; thus allowing it to filter as it joins.
6. probably need to cast IDA as integer (or to the same type as IDB)  I used trim to eliminate spaces but if there are other non-display characters, you'd have issues with the left join matching)

.

```
SELECT guild.*, own.*
FROM dbA.TableA guid
LEFT JOIN  dbB.TableB own
  on cast(trim(replace(guid.idA, ':XYZ', '')) as int) = own.idB
WHERE guid.event like '%2015'
```

Or materialize the transformation first by using a subquery so IDA in its transformed state before the join (like algebra ()'s matter and get processed inside out)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT cast(trim(replace(guid.idA, ':XYZ', '')) as int) as idA
      FROM dbA.TableA guid
      WHERE guid.event like '%2015') B
LEFT JOIN  dbB.TableB own
  on B.IDA  = own.idB
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for taking the time to explain the process. I tried both and I get an error around the replace part. I am now sure why.

Comment: IDA is in tableA correct?  and IDA looks like '123:XYZ' and you want it to look like 123 right?  are both IDA and IDB of the same data type?  (i'm guessing no so maybe we need to cast one to integer?  Lastly, what is the specific error? and for which query?

Comment: If you could provide a guild.ida and one that is to match in own idb and the data type of both columns we could probably figure this out.

Comment: Oh, I think you may have a point. IdA is listed as VARCHAR(100) and IDB as string. How do I fix that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: both need to be of the same data type cast one to the other data type in the above I cast guid.ida to a INT for an example thinking ownidb was int as well but maybe we just need to cast both to varchar(100) or something.  I don't know your data so you'll have to tell us!

Comment: To be more specific https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html cast or convert should do the trick provided the data contained matches.

Comment: yes please, can we cast both as int?( the matching id is eight digits long). Thank you.

Comment: I tried but I failed. May be I am not doing it right. I did this "cast(own.idB as int)"

Comment: to cast a value to an int it must contain only numeric values.  does any of the data contain non-integer values?  What is the error you get when you try?

Comment: IdB is stored as string but it only has numbers in it. The error mentions problem near replace.

Comment: are we sure after the replace of :XYZ that idA only contains numeric values?  does it have spaces or non-display characters (Such as a enter or tab) that could be causing the cast to fail?  The issue to me is we have a data quality problem so the cast fails.  maybe cast as unsigned instead of int?  narrow the problem down to a specific record and two data examples so we can play with specific data.

Comment: I just wanted to circle back. I am using Teradata, that is why it didn't work. I tried replace separately. So what I tried to do was use substring and generate a new id. Thank you very much again.